# How to return only records after certain character?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to return only records after certain character?
Example:

```
'1-1080599'
'021-1080599'
'02 -1080599 '
```

Expected outcome:

```
'1080599'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vkp's solution will work fine, but you could also use PARSENAME to make things slightly simpler, e.g.:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('101-2345678', '-', '.'), 1);
```

If you want to get rid of spaces then you could do this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE('101 - 2345678', '-', '.'), 1));
```

...or even:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE('101 - 2345678', '-', '.'), ' ', ''), 1);
```

Comment: You sure about PARSENAME here? Isn't it only to do with returning part of an object name?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a hack, but it works here as we can just "pretend" that we are resolving objects with a two-part name.  This is why I replace the "-"s with "."s, as PARSENAME expects something like "dbo.table", etc.

Comment: I tip my hat to you good sir! 
You are an devious genius, that's brilliant! :D

Answer (score 5):

This works if you are looking to extract every character after `-` and if there is only one `-` character in the string.

```
select substring(column1,charindex('-',column1)+1,len(column1)) from tablename
where charindex('-',column1) > 0
```

or `RIGHT` can be used.

```
select right(column1,charindex('-',column1)) from tablename
where charindex('-',column1) > 0
```